# creating a file in isolated storage wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am using following code to create a file in isolated storage

```
mystorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (mystorage.FileExists(scanName))
{
    mystorage.DeleteFile(scanName);
}
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(canImage, null);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    wb.SaveJpeg(stream, (int)canImage.Width, (int)canImage.Height, 0, 100);
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream local = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(scanName, FileMode.Create, mystorage))
    {
        local.Write(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, stream.GetBuffer().Length);
    }
}
if (MessageBox.Show("Scan updated successfully") == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{
    App.isTransformRequest = false;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/EditDocument.xaml?paramList=" + App.currentName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

this code works fine. But I want to detect weather the file is completely created or not, and after that only I want to display the success message. The way I am currently working somtimes displays the success message before the complete creation of the file, I want the message to be displayed only after the file is created completely, ie the stream is written completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `BeginWrite` Method of the `IsolatedStorageFileStream` [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.beginwrite%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you can regsiter a ActionCallback to continue with the redirection options in your UI.

Please note, if your callback shows a MessageBox in the UI-Thread, you have to sync the ThreadContext using the `Dispatcher` [(msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190259%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)